# How exactly should `java.util.List.subList()` work?

Tags: java, list

What happens to indices and relationship between indices and list elements, when a `List` is structurally modified through methods of the sub-list obtained through call to `List.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`?

I am **not interested in de-facto operation** as observed in say, Oracle JVM; I am interested in interface behavior specification so one can implement one's own list classes reliably (reliability here would refer to one being able to swap one of Javas list classes with one's own, by sole virtue of implementing `java.util.List` interface).

The [documentation of `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) by Oracle does not seem to shed light on the above. Mind you, *this has nothing to do with attempting to modify the list through any other means than through the sub-list*, this is about modification through the sub-list *only*, as supported by documentation indeed.

#### Example:

Say I have a list of 6 elements `A, B, C, D, E, F`. Calling `subList(1, 4)` on the list yields me a sub-list with elements *B, C, D*. I then call `remove(D)` on this sub-list. I would like to know *which elements will the sub-list contain after `D` is removed*? Some alternatives:

1. *B, C, E* (sub-list retains original index range)?
2. *B, C* (effectively no longer a `subList(1, 4)`)?

My guess is that since the sub-list was specified with `subList(1, 4)` then the "window" on the list itself has to be the same "size", and so `E` slides into view so to speak, because the end index of the view is still 4, which with `D` now gone stretches just beyond `E`. The second alternative does not seem to be very sensible to me, but is an alternative nevertheless.

Comment: Is it really that hard to try it? Literally, 3 lines of code...

Comment: Well, I certainly can do that. I was in the middle of implementing my own list, so somehow the idea did not occur to me. Anyhow, a bit peculiar that this behavior is not specified better in documentation.

Comment: Not specified you say? There's a short essay on behaviour in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList(int,%20int)). In particuar, "the semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list is structurally modified"

Comment: You forgot the end of the sentence: "...in any way other than via the returned list". I have read the docs very thoroughly. What is not specified is whether the view effectively slides or not. I am only modifying the list through the sub-list, so that particular warning does not apply at all, although most people would naturally find it somehow pertaining to my question.

Comment: I don't understand why the only two comments which are directly useless for the scope of my question, are up-voted? Please check the question again and read the parts on how 1) I am after interface specification, not de-facto behavior and 2) I *only* modify the list through sub-list. SO surprises me sometimes...

Comment: It would not make sense to see `E` appear after removing `D`. When removing an element from *any* list, you expect to see a shorter list afterwards. How would you explain that first behaviour to the users of one of your methods? If you say you'll return a `List` which they can modify, it shouldn't matter whether you got that list from a `subList` call or a regular `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Comment: Indeed if you return a modifiable list it shouldn't matter. However, what tipped me off is that even though the method is called `subList`, the docs begin with "Returns a view..." and a view may be said to have constant size, in my example indices [1, 4) which can only mean that `E` "slides" into view after `D` is removed. I could thus explain the behavior by referring users to the concept of a "view", although such view is then not a list, apparently. Anyway, this should be specified in documentation explicitly, and it is, albeit in the wrong place - please see accepted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following quoted specification that may answer the question, has been found in the [documentation of `java.util.AbstractList` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) (and a bit surprisingly, **not** in documentation of `java.util.List`):

> This implementation returns a list that subclasses AbstractList. The subclass stores, in private fields, the offset of the subList within the backing list, the size of the subList **(which can change over its lifetime)**, and the expected modCount value of the backing list.

From the fact that the size of the view can change, it follows that the indices can change as well, meaning that in the example scenario outlined in the question, element `E` will **not** "slide into view". The second alternative is thus correct, as the size of the sub-list after removing `D` is reduced by 1 and the sub-list at that point contains 2 elements `B, C`.

It *may be a deliberate choice* on part of Java designers to specify the above in the `AbstractList` page, as opposed to the documentation page of `List` - so that the latter retains the ambiguity. However, I would expect two different list classes implementing `List` to be easily swappable and compatible on this particular level of detail. Also, not every `List` implementation would extend `AbstractList` - it's a convenience, not a requirement.

Here is to moving the quoted specification (along with some other details) from `AbstractList` page to `List` documentation page.

Comment: There is no 'ambiguity'. It's all specified in the `List` interface, which is a contract that must be obeyed by all implementations. You seem to be making a mountain out of a molehill.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `List`? It is **not** there. There is nothing on the page of `List`, `List.subList` inclusively, which specifies what happens in scenarios like the one I described in my question. And if it is specified, which is what you want me to believe, then why does the page on `AbstractList` bother to write so much about it? The contract you are referring to is what I am after. The contract must be specified, not alluded from between the lines.

Comment: I up-voted this answer because I think it is the most pertinent one to the question. I came upon this post looking for how the heck I was going to implement the subList function for my relatively complex collection which implements the List interface. In order to do it properly I would be creating a class that was almost as complex as my original. So my implementation looks like {throw new NotImplementedException();}. My personal opinion is that this routine is not really appropriate to be placed on such a low level interface.

Answer (score 2):

Since the sublist is a `List`, removing an element must reduce its size. Moreover, the element must also be removed from the backing list. (The Javadoc writes:

> The returned list is backed by this list

and

> The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

Comment: The problem is that one can "back" a list and support all of list operations in **more than one way**.

Comment: Technically nothing in the contract of `remove` says that it must reduce the size of the list.

Comment: @Ian, this has little to nothing to do with my original problem, but I am curious - would you like to invest some time and prove that given that an element is contained in a list, removing it may not reduce the size of the list? Just curious, thank you.

Comment: @amn: Yes, but the requirement that the backing list must support the same operation is only useful if the sublist invokes that operation - and if it does, it's quite clear what the semantics are, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The List interface is the contract, and different implementations are free to do what they like for anything the contract doesn't specify.

It boils down to whether you have a "static" or "dynamic" interpretation of the phrase "view of the portion of this list between *x* and *y*" - is a `subList` a view of that portion of the backing list that was between *x* and *y* at the time the sublist was created (static) or at the time each operation on the sublist is performed (dynamic)? Both readings would be acceptable as per the contract, and different implementations are free to do either.

In particular there's nothing in the contract of `remove` that says that the list *must* be smaller after the removal than it was before, and this isn't as odd a situation as it sounds in the presence of multi threading or event listeners. A case like

```
// lst contains B, C, D
lst.remove(D);
// lst contains B, C, E
```

could be the result of a dynamic `subList` or it could be another thread adding E to the list, or it could be a list implementation that fires events on element removal and an event listener has added E. Either way nothing has broken the List contract.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found, unsurprisingly, in the Javadoc for the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) interface:

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list. ... The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list.

In other words the list can be modified via the sublist.